# How do I print from dart chrome app?

Tags: printing, dart, google-chrome-app

I want to print (on printer, not console) from a dart chrome app.

It is possible to print from chrome apps. Here is [official sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/printing).
This works properly for javascript apps, however I cannot do similar in dart.

Here's what I tried:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:chrome/chrome_app.dart' as chrome;

void main() {
  chrome.app.window.current().print();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

There seems to be no `print()` method in AppWindow object.
The question is how can I **in dart** access `print()` method? I mean the one that is available in javascript in `window` object. Not in regular dart runtime environment but when code is executed as chrome app written in dart.

**Update2:**

I posted the answer. The remaining mystery is how to get the DOM Window object from AppWindow object?

Comment: You need to tell us what "cannot do similar" means and what happened when you tried your code sample.

Comment: First you need to analyze print chrome app. and then you can call some javascript function(brought from original chrome app) from dart code.

Comment: @MarcRochkind `window.print()` works in javascript chrome apps. How to do similar (call window.print()) in dart chrome apps? Hope that's clear now.

Comment: So much for mystery. [Docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#type-AppWindow), `.contentWindow`

Comment: @Xan `.contentWindow` seems to return instance of Window class defined in windows.dart. Id does not have `.print()` nor `.document` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to easier than I thought...

```
window.print()
```

does the job as described in [documentation](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:html.Window#id_print).

Comment: Probably, you can use `console.log()` as well.

Comment: @SunggukLim: `window.console.log`. It's better for objects, since `print(obj)` is more like `window.console.log(obj.toString())`.